# Layout issuein the widget

Tags: android, layout, android-widget

I have created a Widget in with minimum sdk version 14 for a ICS device. I want it now work with every android device that has the minimum sdk version 8 or more. If i am reduces the sdk version in the manifest then the for the is corrupted. Why it is happening. ? How i can create a layout for widget which should same in every device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what your error is (it was hard enough figuring out the gist of your question...) but I would suggest you set your minSDK to 8 and your targetSDK to 14. That way it is backwards compatible but still intended for ICS.